# A taxonomy-provider module: enable/disable vs install/uninstall

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks

If a module provides a taxonomy vocabulary, what should happen in `hook_install`, `hook_enable`, `hook_uninstall` and `hook_disable`?

My main concern is how `hook_uninstall` should differ from `hook_disable`. Should we just `taxonomy_vocabulary_delete()` in both hooks? Should the existing nodes referring to the terms just lose the references upon disabling as well as uninstalling of the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one core module that creates a vocabulary that we can use as a guide: [Forum](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21forum%21forum.module/7).

It creates the vocabulary "Forums" in `hook_enable()` (see [`form_enable()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21forum%21forum.install/function/forum_enable/7)).

It **does not** remove the vocabulary in `hook_disable()` or `hook_uninstall()`. (see [`forum_uninstall()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21forum%21forum.install/function/forum_uninstall/7) - [Forum does not have a `hook_disable()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21forum%21forum.install/function/forum_uninstall/7).

So, to answer your question, **create the vocabulary in `hook_enable()` and don't delete it.**

One other note gleaned from the `forum.install` file that is probably relevant to your module is that you need to make sure your module is loaded after the Taxonomy module. You can do so by settings the module's weight to `1`.

Comment: Ha! Great answer, thanks - I couldn't have given it to myself as I have never ever used Forums in Drupal. I'm still unsure though what sense it makes not to delete the vocabulary when you disable the module that provides it. Logically, everything it provides should become unavailable then.